# While retrieving password code always return try again instead recovering password

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

Here is the C# code

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Mrunal;Initial Catalog=JobPortalDB;Integrated Security=True");
    conn.Open();
    string s1 = "select password from Registration where SecurityQues='" + seqQue.SelectedItem.Text + "' and SecurityAns='" + TextBox2.Text + "' and emailId='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s1, conn);
    SqlDataReader dr;
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
        Label2.Text = dr[0].ToString();
    else
        Label2.Text = "try again";
}
```

Code doesn't show error but it is not working.

Please help if anyone get correction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you debug your code and check your variables? What is _not working_ exactly? What are the types of your columns? Is your query returns any data in SSMS? You should always use parameterized queries. This kind of string concateanations are open for SQL Injection attacks. And use using statement to dispose your sql connections and commands.

Comment: Execute same query in db and check whether is it really exists ?

Comment: Got the above error. actually it was storing zero in secQue field while selecting from dropdownlist. thanks for navigation. but still i didn't get that why dropdownlist stores zero instead selected value form dropdownlist

Comment: here is dropdownlist code  con.Open();
            seqQue.DataTextField = "SeqQue";
            seqQue.DataValueField = "SQId";
            seqQue.DataSource = cmd11.ExecuteReader();
            seqQue.DataBind();
            seqQue.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-------------------------select-------------------------", "0"));
            con.Close();

Comment: Please tell me that you're ***not really*** storing your passwords in ***clear text*** in your database!! ....

Comment: storing password in clear text. it was not problem of password or above code. actually it is problem of dropdownlist

Answer (score 2):

Try using HasRows if you run the query and it returns rows.

Like this:

```
if (dr.HasRows)
    dr.Read();
    Label2.Text = dr[0].ToString();
else
    Label2.Text = "try again";
```

Comment: _If there is one row and there isn't a next row to read dr.Read() returns false_ I don't think so. Default position of the `SqlDataReader` is _before_ the first record at start. That's why, OP _must_ call `Read` to begin access any data.

Comment: yeah I mixed it up, it returns true on one row but false on next.

Comment: But it doesn't need dr.Read() before dr.HasRows.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

```
while(dr.Read())
 {
    if (dr.HasRows)
   {
     Label2.Text = dr["password"].ToString();
   }
  else
   {
     Label2.Text = "try again";
   }
 }
```